# GCP Microsoft AD

Tags: active-directory, google-cloud-platform

I'm reading the [Pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/pricing#licensing) for GCP Microsoft active directory. I know the price for a managed domain is $0.40 per hour per region, but what I don't know is:
Does every server or user that joins the managed domain need a separate license? The servers that are going to join the managed domain are Windows systems

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are these systems Windows or other? For Windows, AFAIK there is no additional charge for AD. I am not sure about Linux. Edit your question with specifics so that you get a good answer.

Comment: Hi John Hanley. Yes, the systems are Windows. I´m going to edit my question. Thank you

Comment: The systems are irrelevant at this point. The cost is for running the AD cluster. This is not "AD licensing", it is "managed active directory as a Azure resource including all the computing and storage". Users/Windows need still their own licensing as applicable - this is just the cost for the setup.

Comment: Hello Gerald. Sure Tom Tom's answer helped me a lot. Thank you everyone!!